# Restrict git branch to Travis CI only

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I have a **Travis CI** processing commits from my **GitHub (Enterprise)** repository, and then pushing the result into a different branch (call it `output`).

The `output` branch should only contain code generated by Travis and no one else. I want to prevent people from pushing to the `output` branch.

I have enable **protected branches**, however from the documentation it says it prevents *force pushes*. I don't think it prevents pushes altogether.

Using GitHub Enterprise 2.4, Travis CI Enterprise (I don't know the version).

Comment: According to [this](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.4/user/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions/), I think each developer account can be configured to read-only.

Comment: Per branch? I think that feature is on a repository-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in GitHub Enterprise 2.6, you can [restrict pushes to a branch](https://help.github.com/enterprise/user/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/) in an Organization to specific users or teams. This will allow you to set up an account, or team, that can be used by Travis CI to commit code back to that branch.

[image: branch restriction gif]

Comment: Better late than never! Thanks